# How I can make this messy code a little bit more clean?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, coding-style, code-cleanup

I'm a newbie in coding javascript, to be honest there is a lot of things I don't understand but i always manage to make things work. I wrote something for odin project but i'm sure it's not as clean and organized as it could be, everything work but i would like it to be as clean as possible. If anyone has suggestions or comments about how to clean/improve the code below that would be awesome. Thanks!
[Live demo:](https://ljaskolka.github.io/odin-tic-tac-toe/)

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
const statusText = document.querySelector("#statusText");
const restartBtn = document.querySelector("#restartBtn");
const winConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
];
let options = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
let currentPlayer = document.createElement("p")
currentPlayer.innerText = "tomato"
let running = false;


const sn0 = document.getElementById("sn0")
const sn1 = document.getElementById("sn1")
const sn2 = document.getElementById("sn2")
const sn3 = document.getElementById("sn3")
const sn4 = document.getElementById("sn4")
const sn5 = document.getElementById("sn5")
const sn6 = document.getElementById("sn6")
const sn7 = document.getElementById("sn7")
const sn8 = document.getElementById("sn8")


initializeGame();

function initializeGame(){
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener("click", cellClicked));
    restartBtn.addEventListener("click", restartGame);
    statusText.textContent = `${currentPlayer}'s turn`;
    running = true;
}
function cellClicked(){
    const cellIndex = this.getAttribute("cellIndex");

    if(options[cellIndex] != "" || !running){
        return;
    }

    updateCell(this, cellIndex);
    checkWinner();
}

function updateCell(cell, index){
    options[index] = currentPlayer.innerText;
    cell.textContent = currentPlayer.innerText;
}
function changePlayer(){
    currentPlayer.innerText = (currentPlayer.innerText == "tomato") ? "flower" : "tomato";
    statusText.textContent = `${currentPlayer.innerText}'s turn`;

    
}

function checkWinner(){
    let roundWon = false;

    for(let i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++){
        const condition = winConditions[i];
        const cellA = options[condition[0]];
        const cellB = options[condition[1]];
        const cellC = options[condition[2]];

        if(cellA == "" || cellB == "" || cellC == ""){
            continue;
        }
        if(cellA == cellB && cellB == cellC){
            roundWon = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(roundWon){
        statusText.textContent = `${currentPlayer.innerText} wins!`;
        running = false;
    }
    else if(!options.includes("")){
        statusText.textContent = `Draw!`;
        running = false;
    }
    else{
        changePlayer();
    }

    if (sn0.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn0.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn0.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn0.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn1.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn1.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn1.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn1.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn2.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn2.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn2.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn2.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn3.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn3.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn3.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn3.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn4.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn4.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn4.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn4.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn5.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn5.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn5.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn5.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn6.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn6.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn6.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn6.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn7.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn7.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn7.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn7.classList.add("flower")
    }

    if (sn8.innerHTML.includes("tomato")) {
        sn8.classList.add("tomato")
    } else if (sn8.innerHTML.includes("flower")){
        sn8.classList.add("flower")
    }
    




}

function restartGame(){
    currentPlayer.innerText = "tomato";
    options = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    statusText.textContent = `${currentPlayer.innerText}'s turn`;
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.textContent = "");
    running = true;
    
    sn0.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn0.classList.remove("flower")

    sn1.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn1.classList.remove("flower")

    sn2.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn2.classList.remove("flower")

    sn3.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn3.classList.remove("flower")

    sn4.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn4.classList.remove("flower")

    sn5.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn5.classList.remove("flower")

    sn6.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn6.classList.remove("flower")

    sn7.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn7.classList.remove("flower")

    sn8.classList.remove("tomato")
    sn8.classList.remove("flower")
}
```

I would like to make this messy code at least a little bit more cleaner

Comment: 1st - define if u'll be using `;` or not. but dont mix 2 ways. 2nd - use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: other than refactoring, you have some issues with responsiveness, on my device, cells don't align at all with the background

Answer (score 0):

So, first, the `options` array us useless, then, why is `currentPlayer` a `<p>` ? It should be a string, it is much easier to work with them.
Exempt that, your code seems pretty good, but some improvements for readability can be made :

- only use `` if you want string interpolation, and whenever is possible, prefer using single quotes (''), in js it is really rare to see double ones ("")
- try adding a little bit of space :

  - `function name(){...}` => `function name () {...}`
  - `if(statement){...}` => `if (statement) {...}`
  - `` `variable: ${variable}` `` => `` `variable: ${ variable }` ``
- and last one, whenever you can, try to avoid brackets : `if (condition) { a += 4 }` => `if (condition) a += 4` (it also works with `else`, `else if`, `for`, `do`, `while`, ...)

This was for the js, but in html, why do you use `cellIndex` and `id` ? By storing cells in an array, we can get rid of them.
But the biggest problems are with the css, you site is simply not responsive at all, background doesn't center for little screens, cells are not matching background and the status is showing only for specific screen sizes.

I tried to highlight all the flaws of your code, but it is not bad at all ! We all do mistakes and without them, we can't make progress. To sum up, I  made your js code a little bit better but it was already pretty good, so I think that the thing you want to focus on is the css (if you want to progress in it, it you just want js, it's no shame)

So, here is my code :

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const cells = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('cell'));
    const statusText = document.getElementById('statusText');
    const restartBtn = document.getElementById('restartBtn');
    const winConditions = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];
    
    const cellClicked = cell => {
        if (cell.classList.contains('tomato') || cell.classList.contains('flower') || !running) return;

        cell.classList.add(currentPlayer);
        checkWinner();
    }

    const togglePlayer = () => {
        currentPlayer = (currentPlayer === 'flower') ? 'tomato' : 'flower';
        updateCurrentPlayerStatus()
    }

    const updateCurrentPlayerStatus = () => {
        statusText.textContent = `${ currentPlayer }'s turn`;
    }

    const checkWinner = () => {
        let roundWon = false;

        for(let i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
            const condition = winConditions[i];
            const toTestCells = condition.map(condition => Array.from(cells[condition].classList.values()).find(e => [ 'tomato', 'flower' ].includes(e)))
            
            if (toTestCells.reduce((g, c) => g === c ? g : '')) {
                roundWon = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (roundWon) {
            statusText.textContent = `${ currentPlayer } wins!`;
            running = false;
        }

        else if (cells.every(e => e.textContent)) {
            statusText.textContent = 'Draw!';
            running = false;
        }

        else
            togglePlayer();
    }

    const restartGame = () => {
        currentPlayer = 'tomato';
        updateCurrentPlayerStatus()

        running = true;
    }

    let currentPlayer = 'tomato';
    let running = false;
    togglePlayer()

    cells.forEach(cell => cell.onclick = () => cellClicked(cell));
    restartBtn.onclick = () => restartGame()
    
    running = true;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

html {
    background: url(https://ljaskolka.github.io/odin-tic-tac-toe/images/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
}

.gameboard {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.cell {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}

.cell-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    max-width: 660px;
    margin-left: 32%;
    margin-top: 7.5%;
}

.tomato {
    background: url(https://ljaskolka.github.io/odin-tic-tac-toe/images/tomato.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:  block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flower {
    background: url(https://ljaskolka.github.io/odin-tic-tac-toe/images/flower.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="index.js"></script>

<div class="game-container">
    <div class="cell-container">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 id="statusText"></h2>
    <button id="restartBtn">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Ask me if you have any question !